# iterate between complex object list

Tags: c#

I use this code to move between instances of a class

```
public class Orders : List<Order>
{       
    int currentIndex = 0;
    public int CurrentIndex {
        get {

            if (currentIndex == Count) {
                currentIndex = 0;
            } else if (currentIndex > Count - 1) {
                currentIndex = Count - 1;
            } else if (currentIndex < 0) {
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
            return currentIndex;
        }
        set { currentIndex = value; }
    }

    public void MoveNext()
    {
        currentIndex++;
    }

    public void MovePrevious()
    {
        currentIndex--;
    }

    public Order Current {
        get {
            return this[CurrentIndex];
        }
    }

}

public class Cart
{
    public string id_ordine { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public double prezzo { get; set; }      
}
```

but I can't figure out hot to make the same  with  complex class that includes a list like in following case.
I have  tried it in many way..

```
public class Order
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string cognome { get; set; }
    public List<OrdersList> ordersList { get; set; }
}

public class OrdersList
{
    public string id_ordine { get; set; }
    public double prezzo { get; set; }      
}
```

to be more specific considider that i have one order that contain more order list

for example

```
   order          orderslist
-------------+----------------- 
name surname   id_ordine prezzo
-------------+-----------------

john doe   -->  1 10
           -->  2 12
           -->  3 22
```

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried?  To access the ordersList in the later code, you should write like `order.ordersList` (given object name of Order class is order). To loop over it you can write like `foreach(var ord in order.ordersList)`

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to follow .NET naming conventions for your properties. It will reduce friction for anyone used to the conventions reading your code.

Comment: You've got some terrible class naming. Why is`OrdersList` just an object with two basic properties? It's not "Orders" or a "List".

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach entirely. A list of items doesn't naturally have a "cursor" in it - it's entirely logical to be able to have multiple cursors, like multiple bookmarks in a book.

I would stick to a `List<OrdersList>` for the list itself, but create an `IndexedListEnumerator<T>` type or something similar, with a `GetIndexedEnumerator()` extension method (probably on `IList<T>`). That would implement `IEnumerator<T>`, but also have a `MovePrevious()` method and an `Index` property.

That separates out the concern for "I want to have a more flexible cursor" from the concern of "I want a list of orders".

I'd also strongly recommend that unless you *really, really* need the sort of "wrap-around" functionality you currently have, that you make the index a simple property, but make `Current` throw an exception when trying to access an invalid index. (So the initial index would be -1, and `Current` would be invalid. Calling `MoveNext()` would take you to index 0 which would be valid for any non-empty list, etc.) As a rough sketch:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{       
    public static IndexedListEnumerator<T> GetIndexedListEnumerator<T>(this IList<T> list) =>
        new IndexedListEnumerator<T>(list);
}

public sealed class IndexedListEnumerator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> list;

    // You *could* restrict this to the range [-1, list.Count] if you wanted.
    public int Index { get; set; }

    // You might want to make this public
    private bool IndexIsValid => Index >= 0 && Index < list.Count;

    public IndexedListEnumerator(IList<T> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
        Index = -1; // Before the first element
    }

    // TODO: Consider using checked to throw an exception around int.MaxValue
    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        Index++;
        return IndexIsValid;
    }

    public bool MovePrevious()
    {
        Index--;
        return IndexIsValid;
    }

    public T Current => list[Index];

    object IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    void IDisposable.Dispose() {}

    void IEnumerator.Reset() => Index = -1;
}
```

Example usage, although you'd normally want to check the result of `MovePrevious()` and `MoveNext()`:

```
List<Order> orders = ...;
var enumerator = orders.GetIndexedListEnumerator();
enumerator.Index = 10;
Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); // Prints orders[10]
enumerator.MovePrevious();
Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); // Prints orders[9]
enumerator.MoveNext();
enumerator.MoveNext();
Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current); // Prints orders[11]
```

Comment: hi Daisy thx a lot it's a great  solution, but i.m not sure if it's ok form my case, because normaly have 1 order and many orderslist so problem is iterate beltween orderlist not order. so can i apply this to orderlist only?

Comment: @andymo: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by that at all. Note that with my solution you can easily call `GetIndexedListEnumerator()` on a `List<OrdersList>`. (I would point out that `OrdersList` is an odd name for something that looks like a single item, mind you.) It would help if you'd make the question a lot clearer about what you're trying to achieve. I've given the best answer I can with limited information, but there's only so much we can do while the question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: it may be a wrong naming solution. :-) it come from my custormer. anyway consider this
1 order --> many orderslist @Daisy

Comment: @andymo: If your customer is making odd naming choices, I would consider it part of the *value* you can provide to point that out. Don't just go along with whatever they suggest, if you think it's wrong.

Comment: @andymo: And "consider this 1 order --> many orderslist" doesn't tell me anything about what you're trying to do with it or in what way my code doesn't help you do that. *Please* take a bit of time to clearly express what you're trying to achieve, and edit that into the question.

Comment: @andymo: I'm afraid that's still really unclear. You've shown an order with multiple items, but you haven't given us any indication of what you're trying to achieve with it. My code would let you navigate forward and back within that list of order items - isn't that what you want? If not, what *do* you want?

Comment: yes @Daisy i moving between item of orderslist and go to begin when reached the end (kind of circular )

Comment: @andymo: I would question the design there, as you'd never know when you'd reached the end - but with my existing code you *could* achieve it by saying `if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) { enumerator.Index = 0; }` for example. I think you probably need to read through my answer again, as I believe it does do everything you need it too... and if it doesn't, please edit the question again to be *absolutely clear* what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: i don't want to bothering you... i'm trying to implement your code, but it gave me lot of error. i keep on tring